# How to open pdf file stored in firebase storage in next tab

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

[image: creenshots]

In the above image, on clicking ViewFile, i can see file URL in console (bottom right), on clicking that link, file is opening in next tab. I want file to directly open in next tab when I click on 'View File'.
Below im dropping my code, can anyone help me doing it.

```
DownloadEvidence(){
    const files = firebase.storage().ref('pdf/498df57c-c470-40e4-8077-0fa3ae4863a4.pdf/');
    files.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      console.log(url);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DownloadEvidence(){
    const files = firebase.storage().ref('pdf/498df57c-c470-40e4-8077-0fa3ae4863a4.pdf/');
    files.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      window.open(url, "_blank")
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open(url, '_blank');`